# Nested resource on validation error will allow edit on all children model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following relationship: `:discussion has_many :posts`, and I have the Post model nested inside the Discussion.

The discussions#show view has a form allowing users to create post (reply) on that discussion.

In my update action I have:

```
if @discussion.update_attributes(params[:discussion])
  format.html { redirect_to(@discussion, :notice => 'success') }
else
  format.html { render :action => "edit" }
end
```

I used `field_for :posts, @post` to A) allow nested model update B)restrict the form to only allow single post create.

However if the validation fails, the page will show all posts belonging to the form in editable form. I only want to allow the user to re-edit the single post. Is there a good way to achieve this?

If validation fails, the post is not saved and I don't know how to pin-point the particular new post.

I was thinking maybe I shouldn't create a post through discussion form, since it is like a layer of overhead. But now I have nested it, I can no longer route to the *posts/new* view.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question.  If the user can edit all posts through the discussion form before submitting, then wouldn't it make sense that they should be able to do the same when editing in response to a validation error?  If there are so many posts in a discussion that this doesn't make sense, then using fields_for is probably not the best design in any case.

Comment: I used `field_for :posts, @post` to restrict the form to only allow single post create/edit. That's in the show action. Only when the validation fails the edit view is rendered, and all other posts are displayed and editable.

Comment: What does your edit action do to limit the form to a single post?  Whatever that is, you probably just need to make sure your update action does the same before trying to render :action => 'edit' (which will simply render the view associated with the edit action).

Comment: I don't have restriction on edit action yet. You see, the show action allows users to create post (reply) on that discussion. If validation fails, the post is not saved and I don't know how to pin-point it. Sorry about the lack of clarification by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I came up with to only allow single post edit:

```
else
  format.html { 
    @post = @discussion.posts.last
    render :action => "edit"
  }
```

It's a bit hackish, hackers can still send hacked POST messages and alter other posts. So better and clean solutions are welcomed.